# How to set Font to Subtitle in pichart using jfreechart?

Tags: image, jfreechart, font-size, subtitle

I have generated piechart which has subtitles 
 i.e. Cash ,total,Security 
now problem is that subtitles are appearing bigger than actual piechart.

[image]

How can I set font to those subtitles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Labels**

```
StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator slbl = new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0} [{1}]",new DecimalFormat("#,##0"),new DecimalFormat("0%"));
piePlot.setLabelGenerator(slbl);
```

**For the font**

```
new Font("SansSerif", Font.ITALIC, 7)
```

I suggest you try to add that Font into the `StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator`

Comment: Wekcome to Stack overflow.  Thanks for the answer.  I edited it a little to put the code into the standard format.  You can format code blocks by leaving a blank line before them and indenting 4 spaces. For inline code, surround it with backticks.